# What is happening inside the constructor?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

Can anyone explain what is happening inside Constructor.

I could not understand this section of code inside constructor:
`To.AddRange(to.Select(x => new MailboxAddress("email", x)));`

```cs
  public class Message
  {
      public List<MailboxAddress> To { get; set; }
      public string Subject { get; set; }
      public string Content { get; set; }
      public Message(IEnumerable<string> to, string subject, string content)
      {
          To = new List<MailboxAddress>();
          To.AddRange(to.Select(x => new MailboxAddress("email", x)));
          Subject = subject;
          Content = content;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the code that isn't relevant and added some code comments to give you a high level understanding.

```cs
  public class Message
  {
      // Declaration
      public List<MailboxAddress> To { get; set; }

      public Message(IEnumerable<string> to)
      {
          // Instantiation
          To = new List<MailboxAddress>();
          // Population
          To.AddRange(to.Select(x => new MailboxAddress("email", x)));
      }
  }
```

The details can be broken down into:

1. `To.AddRange(...)` is a method that appends a list of items
2. `to.Select(...)` is a linq method that iterates through an `IEnumerable<T>`
3. `x => new MailboxAddress("email", x)` is a lambda expression that takes a string as input and returns a `MailboxAddress`

The `Message` constructor is taking a list of strings, converting them to `MailboxAddress` objects, and then storing them in the public variable `To`.

You could alternatively write this using a `foreach` loop:

```cs
  public class Message
  {
      // Declaration
      public List<MailboxAddress> To { get; set; }

      public Message(IEnumerable<string> to)
      {
          // Instantiation
          To = new List<MailboxAddress>();
          // Population
          foreach (var x in to)
          {
              To.Add(new MailboxAddress("email", x));
          }
      }
  }
```